# Get Filters selected in admin sales order grid

Tags: magento2.2, grid, filter, order-grid

How can I retrieve the selected filters when a sales order admin grid loads programmatically in Magento 2?

For e.g., if the filter is selected as Status = Cancelled, I want to be able to access it programmatically.

Comment: Access what? The filter value and / or column name of the applied filter in code?

Comment: Yes, The filter value and column name of the applied filter in code @DominicXigen

Comment: Do we have any solution here